# Why this C-program doesn't gives the reverse of given string?

Tags: c, reverse, c-strings, pointer-arithmetic, function-definition

Why this program doesnot gives reverse of the given string `computer`, though the `length()` function works fine(when I comment other codes and only run that part) and gives output correct but the second `reverse()` function is not giving any output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

 int length(char *);
 char *reverse(char *, int);

int main()
{
char word[] = "COMPUTER";
int count;

count = length("COMPUTER");

printf("%s", reverse(word, count));

}

int length(char *p)
{
int count;
for (count = 0; *(p + count) != '\0'; count++);
    
 return (count);
 }

 char *reverse(char *p, int count)
 {
char temp;
for (int i = 0; i < count / 2; i++)
{
    temp = *(p + i);
    *(p + i) = *(p - (count - 1) - i);
    *(p - (count - 1) - i) = temp;
}
return (p);
 }
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Shouldn't your `- (count - 1)`s be `+ (count - 1)`?

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger. Look at the `count` value, Look at what characters are being swapped at each step, dump the `p` contents, etc. It should be obvious with some moderate debugging.

Comment: Maybe writing as `p[i]` and `p[count - i - 1]` makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These expression statements

```
*(p + i) = *(p - (count - 1) - i);
*(p - (count - 1) - i) = temp;
```

are incorrect,

It seems you mean

```
*(p + i) = *(p + ( count - 1 ) - i);
*(p + (count - 1) - i) = temp;
```

Also instead of this statement

```
count = length("COMPUTER");
```

it will be more logically consistent to write

```
count = length( word );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t length( const char * );
char * reverse( char *, size_t );
 
int main(void) 
{
    char word[] = "COMPUTER";
    size_t count = length( word );

    puts( reverse( word, count ) );

}

size_t length( const char *p )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    while ( *( p + count ) != '\0' ) ++count;
    
    return count;
}

char * reverse( char *p, size_t count )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < count / 2; i++ )
    {
        char temp = *( p + i );
        *( p + i ) = *( p + count - 1 - i );
        *( p + count - 1 - i ) = temp;
    }
    
    return p;
}
```

The program output is

```
RETUPMOC
```